# Get all commits during working hours (or after hours)

Tags: git

Is there any way to get a list of commits that happend lets say between 09:00 and 17:00, and their time ?

The only thing I can think about is sending the output to a file, and then trying to parse it...

Comment: You are aware of the caveat with the two timestamps stored in a commit, namely that they have nothing to do with the point in time when a commit was published to a branch? Depending on what you're actually trying to measure these timestamps might not be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ended up using the following Git command for testing:

```
git log  --pretty=format:'%h|%C(green)%aN%C(reset)|%C(yellow)%ae%C(reset)|%C(cyan)%ad%C(reset)|%s'
```

Then, I've used this for formatting into an easy to read and parse input file:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%H|%aN|%ae|%ad|%s' > some_file.txt
```

And eventually decided to go with doing the following, which outputs a JSON that can be easily deserialized into a POCO:

```
log --date=iso --pretty=format:'{\"ShortHash\":\"%h\",\"Name\":\"%an\",\"Email\":\"%ae\",\"Date\":\"%ad\",\"Subject\":\"%s\"}'
```

For the "smarts" I've ended running a linqpad script against the above output file, with the brunt of the work done by:

```
bool BetweenBusinessHours(string anHour, string aStart = "08:30", string anEnd="17:00") {
    return (anHour.CompareTo(aStart) > 0)
        && (anHour.CompareTo(anEnd)  < 0) ;
}

bool DuringWeekend(string aShortDay) {
    return aShortDay.Equals("Sat")
        || aShortDay.Equals("Sun") ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, actually Eugene is very close to what you want. Try this:

`git log --after="09:00" --before="17:00"`

Omitting the day should work as you expected. This gives you the *raw* output, if you desire a different output try `git log --pretty=tformat:"%C(cyan)%ad%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08%x08 %C(bold red)%h %C(bold blue)%<(22)%ae %C(reset)%s"` or do your own Google for `git formatting log`.

I did a brief search on Google with [git logs between hours](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+logs+between+hours&gws_rd=ssl) and [git see daily logs](https://www.google.com/search?q=git+see+daily+logs&gws_rd=ssl) which lead to more advanced features and outputs if you are looking to something more naive.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will look like `git log --after="2014-01-05 09:00" --before="2014-01-05 17:00"`.

See the reference here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

Comment: wouldn't this give me the commits for a specific date? (in your case, either first of may, or fifth of january, depending on the format of date time). I'm trying to figure out a way to get all the commits between hours across all days.

Comment: I guess you'll have to run shell script with a loop during the time period with this command.